# ExtensionMapper.java in Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java

i am facing problem whenever i am running my wsdl2java the `ExtensionMapper` class is generating in different different packages.

Example :First time ran the wsdl2java
   result : `ExtensionMapper.java`  generated in

```
com.acis.webservice.result
```

Example:Second time ran the wsdl2java
   result :`ExtensionMapper.java`  generated in `

```
com.acis.webservice.status
```

Now this tedious for each run the file shifting its position and my problem is difficult to maintain a SVN version for the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the namespace of the schema in the wsdl you use changes. Use `-ns2p` to map namespaces to java packages. or `namespaceToPackages="${nameSpace}=${nsPackage}"` in if using ant task

Comment: @ Cirkel ,Can you help me on that i am using eclipse ide for the wsdl2java generation

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with axis2 1.6 even though we are using the namespace2java option.  We build it from the command line instead of ant.  This was not a problem with our previous axis2 versions (1.5, 1.5.1).  Not sure what has changed to cause this mapperclass not be matched to the namespace "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace".

However it seems to be only the case on some of our code..not all of it.  That is some mapperclasses are packaged correct, but others aren't.